# Is this a subjunctive mood?

Tags: subjunctives

> I look into my glass,
>  And view my wasting skin,
>  And say,
>   **Would God it came to pass**
>  My heart had shrunk as thin.
>
> For then, I, undistrest
>  By hearts grown cold to me,
>  Could
>   lonely wait my endless rest
>  With equanimity.
>
> But Time, to make me grieve,
>  Part steals, lets part abide;
>   And shakes this fragile frame at eve
>  With throbbings of noontide.
>   
>  (Virginia Woolf, To the Lighthouse, Penguin Classics’ note.9)

Is the bold part a subjunctive mood –– would it came God to pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variation on the rather old-fashioned construction *Would that ...* . For example:

> Would that I could help you.
>
> Would that the fighting stopped (would stop).

It is equivalent to saying:

> I wish that I could help you.
>
> I wish that the fighting would stop.

*Would God it came to pass* means something like:

> I pray to God that it will happen.

Comment: +1 You might explain that *come to pass* is an idiom meaning *happen, eventuate* and that *God* is the subject of the clause: *May God will that it come to pass*.

Comment: Thanks for adding to my explanation. A follow-on question could ask about the difference, if any, between _Would God that ..._ and _Would to God that ..._ . The former seems to be a direct invocation and the latter more of an expression of a heartfelt wish: _Would to God that their dog would stop its incessant barking_.